# Python: pandas.DataFrame.plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to plot the following:

```
df[['V1','V2']].plot(subplots=True,xticks=df['Dates'])
```

I receive the following error:

> Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'

How can I make it to plot dates in a proper way?

Comment: try look at `matplotlib` `plot_date`

Comment: I managed to plot it with matplotlib. I would like to know if there is a way by using pandas.DataFrame.plot

Comment: How about provide some example data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you set your Timestamps to be the index of the dataframe the x axis labels will be your timestamps.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4,[72,5]))
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
df.index= pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=72, freq='H')

df[['col1','col2']].plot()
```

This will result in the following plot.

[image: plot result]